# Fedora 36 fails to suspend

Tags: fedora, suspend

Ever since I upgraded, my Fedora 36 fails to suspend, no matter what approach I take (`systemctl suspend`, the suspend button, closed lid).
The system is up to date and I don't receive any kind of failure message.

`dmesg` shows this as the last entries after the suspend command:

```
wlp1s0: deauthenticating from c1:2e:16:4f:9a:ae by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s20f0u1u1u2: link becomes ready
r8152 2-1.1.2:1.0 enp0s20f0u1u1u2: carrier on
wlp1s0: authenticate with a5:ae:55:3e:c1:3d
wlp1s0: send auth to a5:ae:55:3e:c1:3d (try 1/3)
wlp1s0: authenticate with a5:ae:55:3e:c1:3d
wlp1s0: send auth to a5:ae:55:3e:c1:3d (try 1/3)
wlp1s0: authenticated
wlp1s0: associate with a5:ae:55:3e:c1:3d (try 1/3)
wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from a5:ae:55:3e:c1:3d (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=4)
wlp1s0: associated
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: That's very unlikely to be the culprit. Please upload the entire dmesg to e.g. pastebin (with expiration).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That same block repeats itself every 3 hours (the set suspend delay) with nothing else.